# Verify certificate chain against CRL with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, verification, certificate-revocation

I'm trying to learn about certificate and CRL handling, so I created the following example certificate chain:

Root CA (self-signed) → Intermediate CA (signed by Root CA) → Server Cert (signed bei Intermediate CA)

Now I would like to test certificate revocation to be effective. To do so, I revoke the Server Cert and create a CRL file (of the Intermediate CA) accordingly. The X509v3 CRL Distribution Points are present in all of the certificate files, and they are accessible via http, like:

```
X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:
    Full Name:
      URI:http://127.0.0.1:80/intermediate_ca.crl
```

(Which is the CRL I just created. (The same for the Root CA CRL at http://127.0.0.1:80/ca.crl.) I double-checked they are really present and accessible at that URI.)

Next, I `cat` the Root CA `pem` file and the Intermediata CA `pem` file into `CAChain.pem`.

I'd like to have a command that receives the Server Cert and the `CAChain.pem` and "crawls up" the certificate chain in order verify it in total.

I tried going with

`openssl verify -extended_crl -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile CAChain.pem -verbose serverCert.pem`

but I just get:

```
Error loading CRL from http://127.0.0.1:80/ca.crl
140041593399104:error:27076072:OCSP routines:parse_http_line1:server response error:crypto/ocsp/ocsp_ht.c:260:Code=404,Reason=Not Found
...
error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
```

Again, the CRL is *really* present at the URI denoted. That's why I can't explain the error 404. (Additionally it seems a little strange to me, that the error arises from an OSCP module as I'm just using CRL at the moment.)

I would highly appreciate if someone could tell me what my mistake is and how I can achieve what I originally intended (verifying the whole cert chain using the CRLs). Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) yes, `load_cert_crl_http` in `apps/apps.c` (re)uses the `OCSP_REQ*` functions in `crypto/ocsp/ocsp_ht.c` for HTTP, presumably because they had already been written (several versions earlier) before `-crl_download` was added in 1.0.2. (2) You say the CRLs are available at `/intermediate_ca.crl` and `/root_ca.crl`, but then that at least one is at `/ca.crl`. Are those both correct? How are you checking? If you're using a browser or similar, try something simple like `curl` to make sure you're not getting any caching, proxy, or user-agent based 'feature'. ...

Comment: ... (3) in case you don't know, according to SSL/TLS standards server should send chain except (optionally) root so client doesn't _need_ intermediate stored, although it may choose to; to more exactly match the standard case in `verify` use `-untrusted intermediate(s)` and `-CAfile/path root(s)only`. (This won't affect your current issue though.)

Comment: (1) OK, thanks for clarifying!
(2) Sorry, my bad. The root CA crl is indeed located at `ca.crl`. (I found that a littly ugly so I had changed it in the first part of my post but not further below.) I have edited my question now to correct it. I'm just doing a `wget http://127.0.0.1:80/ca.crl` (from the same machine of course) and it'll download the CRL just fine. There is no proxy or something else in between...
(3) Thank you again - I have really been a little confused about where to send/create the chain!

Comment: Very weird. If it were me I would debug the server to see why the different result if possible, and otherwise debug the client (using openssl built with symbols) or interpose an HTTP inspector like Burp,Charles,Fiddler to try to figure out the difference. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there were mainly two mistakes I had made:

- The CRL file mandatorily has to be in DER format, which I did not know. (Conversion from the PEM format is simple: `openssl crl -in ${crlFile}.pem -outform DER -out ${crlFile}`).
- Of course, a certicate's CRL distribution point has to be the one of its *parent* CA. (So, e. g. for my intermediate CA, it must be the one of the root CA.)

Keeping this in mind and also chaining the intermediate CA certs to the server certs, as dave_thompson_085s very helpful comments suggested, the original command

```sh
openssl verify -extended_crl -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile CAChain.pem -verbose serverCert.pem
```

works now.

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ahuemmer/d390e18a9923b0b8638bcfbd2fb33a8a) of what I have done so far. It's still pretty ugly - I will tidy it up and also experiment with OCSP in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, a certicate's CRL distribution point has to be the one of its parent CA. (So, e. g. for my intermediate CA, it must be the one of the root CA.)

The issuer of a Certificate Revocation List (CRL) doesn't always have to be associated with the certificates revoked. As mentioned in [RFC-5280 page 55](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#page-55), if the CRL's designated certificates extend beyond the scope of CRL's issuer, it qualifies as an indirect CRL. Indirect CRLs could even be issued without the issuer's private key. Although many clients do not inherently support indirect CRLs, leading to CRLs mostly being issued by the certificates' original issuers.

I came across an article detailing the issuing and validation of indirect CRLs: https://grimoire.carcano.ch/blog/indirect-crl-generation-crl-validation-and-ocsp-validation/