# openssl verify client certificate with crl file and ca file (unable to get certificate CRL)

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have

- ca file (ca.cert.pem)
- client file (client.cert.pem)
- crl file (test.crl)

I want to verify the client certificat.

I used:

```
openssl verify -extended_crl -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile ca.cert.pem -verbose client.cert.pem
```

I am getting this error

```
error 3 at 1 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
```

what wrong ?

I read this answer [Verify certificate chain against CRL with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684888/verify-certificate-chain-against-crl-with-openssl) but i dont have any chain.

Comment: You are not providing the CRL you have (this would be `-CRLfile` option) but instead expect openssl to download the CRL. Does the client certificate even contain a link where the CRL can be downloaded? Does this link work?

Comment: I did openssl verify -crl_check_all -CRLfile test.pem -CAfile ca.cert.pem client.cert.pem and i am getting error

error 3 at 1 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you really did instead of correcting yourself only in the comment. Please also provide the either the files you used for testing or a reproducible way to create these files, so that others can reproduce exactly what you did.